# WSO2 Update Manager (WUM) vs Puppet

Tags: wso2, puppet, wso2-esb

I want to use Puppet to manage configuration of my WSO2 ESB instances. Newly, WSO2 launch WSO2 Update Manager (WUM) which it is great tool describing [here](http://wso2.com/blogs/thesource/2016/09/keep-your-wso2-products-up-to-date-with-wum/?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=organicpost&utm_campaign=tworgblog_sep16).

Is it possible to use both tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WUM doesn't allow you to manage configurations, what it does is, It will give you a pack with latest patches applied. So WUM won't replace puppet, for configuration management you still need Puppet.So yes you can use both.

Comment: Thanks, I know they are differents tools, and WUM does not manage configurations, but I was not sure about using both.